# Is it possible to add gradient to an element that corresponds to its width?

Tags: html, css

```css
.surf_bar_container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px #888888;
}

.surf_bar {
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, salmon);
  line-height: 40px;
}

p {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf_bar_container">
  <div class="surf_bar" style="width:93%;">
    <p>93%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am setting its width serverside (in this case i just hardcoded `93%`). But is it possible to make it more red the closer to 100% i get and more green the closer to 0% it gets?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by *more red* Or *more green*? May be an image if you could show us?

Comment: Put the gradient in the background, so that it's always 100% width. Then hide it with a div ontop and uncover it based on the percentage rate.

Comment: Yoo mean like this? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yzdmBq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this purpose. Based on my understanding of your question, you want the gradient to be 100% of the bar width, but want part of the gradient masked out based on the percentage value. In this case, you will want to:

- use the gradient on the `.surf_bar_container` itself
- the `.surf_bar` markup will remain untouched
- use `display: flex` on the container, and create an `::after` pseudo-element that will take up the remaining width unoccupied by `.surf_bar` using `flex: auto`

[CSS3 flexbox module is quite widely supported among browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). For those using the legacy flexbox specification, the solution is still workable since it is a very basic property of flexbox.

A proof-of-concept below:

```css
.surf_bar_container {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green, salmon);
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px #888888;
  display: flex;
}

.surf_bar_container::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #ddd;
  flex: auto;
}

.surf_bar {
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 40px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf_bar_container">
  <div class="surf_bar" style="width:15%;">
    <p>15%</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="surf_bar_container">
  <div class="surf_bar" style="width:85%;">
    <p>85%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! If I could upvote u twice, I would.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple colors in between and I hope this can be what you are looking for. Please ignore the colors if you don't like them, you can use your own color hex values.

**[Check the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/demaxglobal/fmyrs565/1/)**

```
 .surf_bar_container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px #888888;
  }
  .surf_bar {
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green , lightgreen, salmon, red);
  line-height: 40px;
  }
  p {
  padding-right: 10px;
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx! But I think u missunderstood my question. If width is 5% I want (almost) no red, and the bigger width get, the more red gradient I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function barSizeChange(){
var div_height1 = $(".surf_bar_container”).width();
var div_height2 = $(".surf_bar”).width();
if(div_height2 > .6*div_height1){
      $(".surf_bar").css({ "background": "linear-gradient(to right, 
green , green)"}) 
}
}
```

jQuery Check... for the width.
Hope this is what u want.